# How to make an interactive ImageMap in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create some sort of map, which is actually a large image, that needs to have specific spots where you can touch to see more info. So far I've found [**react-native-image-mapper**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-mapper) which seems to work for the image map but I haven't been able to figure out how to make the pan effect to drag and move around the image inside the View.

Can anyone please help me out or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!